# ASP.NET MVC control similar to forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modularity

first let me say, I  have started my first ASP.NET MVC (4) application. Before that, I was a forms developer. I love the MVC concept, even though I have not yet fully understood.

In ASP forms times, we could create a control to encapsulate and use it again. I could not figure out yet which element is similar in MVC. I created a Viewed User Control but that hasnt a code-behind file..

Can you give me an example?

Best regards
Patrik

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but perhaps you might be interested in [Partial Views](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/).  Here is an article on [resuable UI Components](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_ReusableUI.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of user controls, try razor helpers refer this link for details. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Even though MVC3 is discussed in the blog post, no need to worry. It is not changed in MVC4